# how to share image with text in IOS with Flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, image, dart, share

I want to share images and text via Native Share Popup on both platforms (Android & IOS).

I tried “ShareExtend” for sharing images with text, and it’s working fine with Android devices but not with IOS.

Here is code;

```
ShareExtend.shareMultiple(
        ['filename.png'],
        "image",
        subject: "share muti image",

        extraTexts: ["Hello World"],
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

As I remember, this lib is not support for sharing both text and image on iOS. It just providers a way for sharing with system ui and limited by system api.Try using another one, eg: share_plus

```
https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus
```

Comment: I tried with share_plus: ^4.5.3 and not fulfilling my requirement, meaning that, I can not share images and text. In addition, I checked the git open issue and found this same issue there.

Let me know if you have any other solutions.

Comment: Please chek this,
https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/issues/1689